# How do you only display decimal places if they aren’t zero?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, format, number

I have numerical data being passed into an email to two decimal places, it could be 10.00 or 10.16 for example.

Is there a way I can easily show just 10 if the original number is 10.00, but show 10.16 if it’s 10.16?

I can use the format number function to show a certain number of decimal places, but unsure how to make it conditional.

(Sorry if this is a basic question, I’m still learning)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can round down the input number then compare 2 numbers together to decide which one you want to display

Try something like this:

```
%%[
    /* set @num = 10.00 */
    set @num = 10.90

    /* round down number */
    set @roundedNum = FormatNumber(@num,"N0","en-US")
    if @num == @roundedNum then
        set @finalNum = @roundedNum
    else
        set @finalNum = @num
    endif
]%%

%%=v(@finalNum)=%% <!-- 10.90 -->
```

Comment: Try it here: https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/HMv5G7wD